# "type of expression is ambiguous without more context" with an array

Tags: arrays, swift

I am in xCode 7.3 playground and learning Swift 2.0.

I have an array as follows:

```
var arrayName:Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, "Mike"]
```

And i'm getting the following error:

> type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Now when i remove the string from the array the error disappears, however apparently Swift allows multiple types in arrays so I dont understand why its erroring?

any ideas?

cheers

Comment: Problem was because I had not imported UIKit.

Answer (score 3):

Error says all. You can fix it like this, for example:

```
var arrayName: Array<AnyObject> = [1, 2, 3, 4, "Mike"]
```

or, simplier,

```
var arrayName = [1, 2, 3, 4, "Mike"]
```

then `arrayName` will get type `Array<NSObject>` implicitly.

Its all about type recognizing. You have two options: use explicit **full** type declaration, or you can let swift compiler try recognize type

Comment: I see, thanks. Although your first example gave: error: value of type 'Int' does not conform to expected element type 'AnyObject'

Comment: and your second example still gives me the initial error message

Comment: @MikeMeade I never used playground. Maybe there are some restricts in it? I have Xcode 7.3, and trust me, both lines absolutely valid in regular code and compiled without errors.

Comment: thanks, thats helpful. maybe its just a playground issue then. cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out

[Ray Wenderlich on Swift Arrays](https://www.raywenderlich.com/74138/swift-language-faq)

> So, arrays can only contain one type of object? What if I want varied types?
>   In Swift you are highly encouraged to make strongly typed arrays that contain only one type of object, with syntax like this:

```
var goodArray: [String] = ["foo", "bar"]
```

> That said, technically you can still create arrays that contain multiple types of objects. However, before you do this you should be asking yourself why you want to do this. In most cases it does not make the best sense and you can likely engineer your solution to be cleaner.
>   With that said, here’s how you can create a Swift array with varying types of objects within it by using AnyObject:

```
var brokenArray: [AnyObject] = ["foo", 1, 12.23, true]
```

TL;DR:- Arrays are strongly typed on iOS. If you need to insert elements of multiple type, make them of type "AnyObject". Would not recommend this though.

Comment: thanks, however your example still errors. I get I probably wouldnt ever need to or want to mix types, however I dont understand why it is erroring if you technically should be able to mix them.

Comment: What exactly is the error message that you are receiving? And technically you cannot mix them. The array takes the type of the first element that is in it if you do not give it one but it is always strongly typed

Comment: ah, I have realised it is because I had not imported UIKit. problem solved, no errors now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another option, which is useful when concatenating 2 arrays of objects that *conform to the same protocol*, is to **upcast** each array individually to the protocol:

`let arrayName = [1, 2, 3, 4] as [AnyObject] + ["Mike"] as [AnyObject]`

As said, this will come in more handy when working with protocols:

```
protocol Foo {}
struct Bar: Foo {}
struct Baz: Foo {}

let barArray = [Bar()]
let bazArray = [Baz()]
let fooArray = barArray as [Foo] + bazArray as [Foo]
```